# Is there kind of runtime C++ assembler library around?

Tags: c++, runtime, reflection.emit, assembly

For my small hobby project I need to emit machine code from C++ program in runtime. I have base address 0xDEADBEEF and want to write something like this:

```
Assembler a((void*)0xDEADBEEF);
a.Emit() << 
  Push(Reg::Eax) <<
  Push(Reg::Ebx) <<
  Jmp(0xFEFEFEFE);
```

Inline assembler isn't my choice because generated machine code is dependent of the program state.

Does anybody know any existing library for doing this? If no, would it be a good idea to develop one from scratch and make it open source? (I mean, will anybody ever use this library if it existed?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Nicolas Capen's [softwire](http://sourceforge.net/projects/softwire/).  Its really not supported any more as he now works on a similar product at Transgaming called SoftAsm.  Still it kinda does what you want.

**Edit June 2014**: - It appears the sourceforge link above has been removed but it appears to be available under an LGPL license [here](https://code.google.com/p/softwire/).

Comment: This answer is outdated now. At least I can't find any downloads on that page

Answer (score 9):

Check out [Asmjit](http://code.google.com/p/asmjit/). It seems to be the thing you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a overkill, because it supports many platforms, has its own intermediate language, does optimizations, etc, but the http://llvm.org/ seems to be a god try.

Comment: That's a cool project, but it's too heavyweight and (as far as I understand) doesn't give me fine control over generated instructions. Thanks anyway.