# Inline assembly to bytes in C++

Tags: c++, assembly, code-injection

I want to write memory to a process for code injection. But after the WriteProcessMemory, the result assembly code is not the same. I use Cheat Engine to do checking. Can anyone help?

Here is the assembly function:

```
void tidy() {
    DWORD addr = 0x4AED10;
    _asm{
        pushad
        pushfd
        mov eax, addr
        call eax
        popfd
        popad
        ret
    }
}

void callAsm(const char* processName, PVOID CallFun)
{
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcessEasy(processName);
    LPVOID allocAddr = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, 0x20, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READ);
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, allocAddr, CallFun, 0x20, NULL);

}
```

I just call:

```
callAsm("xxx.exe",tidy);
```

The written memory in allocated address 0x3640000 becomes:

```
E9 98190000 jmp 0364199D
E9 27190000 jmp 03641931
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve. What you're doing looks unlikely to work ever.

Comment: I want to do code cave injection. I have read some tutorial writing a byte array to achieve this, but we have to convert it to machine code before that. Is there a way to convert the asm to bytes automatically?

Comment: _'Is there a way to convert the asm to bytes automatically?'_ Use an assembler?

Comment: yes, like what this website does: [https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly), C++ can do that?

Comment: _'C++ can do that?'_ Yes! You can call any other program from c++ code using the correct OS specific functions.

Comment: Do you know some tutorial or example to achieve this? such as: 
pushad->0x60, pushfd-> 0x9C...

Comment: Why would you need to convert the assembly code to machine code at runtime? Unless you're writing something like a JIT compiler, but at that point writing an assembler would be the easy part (not that having a textual respresentation of the code in a JIT makes much sense to me). Otherwise, just compile the assembly code separately with nasm/fasm/yasm/masm/tasm/whatever, dump the resulting machine code to an unsigned char array and put that in your C++ source file.

Comment: What I actually do is to build a machine to play a game. It is efficient when I call the build-in assembly function. The procedure begins with 4 parts.
1. OpenProcess
2. VirtualAllocEx
3. WriteProcessMemory
4. CreateRemoteThread 
I need to write the assembly code to memory for injection in part(3). If the function need to passing different variable, it needs to convert asm to machine bytes. Therefore, I am looking for a efficient converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was [already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787002/is-there-kind-of-runtime-c-assembler-library-around) on SO, but in a bit different terms. There are numerous libraries for runtime assembly compilation with C++ syntax.

There's an [asmjit](https://github.com/kobalicek/asmjit) that looks like

```
c.test(op, op);
c.jne(L_Subtract);
c.add(a, b);
c.jmp(L_Skip);
...
auto res = c.make(); // compile it into bytecode.
```

Also, you can use quite outdated [softwire](http://sourceforge.net/projects/softwire/) or even [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) for a full-featured code generation.